# Angular 2 - Single Form Component for Create and Edit

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I'm looking for some good advice / best practice to reuse my Form Component.

### Data Model:

```
class Contact {
  id?: String;
  name: String;
}
```

- When **creating** a new `Contact` there's of course **no `id`**, that's why it's optional in the model.
- When **editing** a `Contact` there is an `id`, but it's not editable and thus it's not part of the form.

### Behavior:

The Edit and the Create view should use the same Form `@Component`, because the available fields are the same, and validation constraints are the same, too.

**But** both views must have different actions. E.g. the Edit view must have a Delete and Reload button, and of course the Save buttons of both views must behave differently (Create makes a `POST` request, Edit makes a `PATCH` request).

### What I tried / Problems:

I created a `ContactCreateComponent` and a `ContactEditComponent`, which both have the `<contactForm [contact]="contact"></contactForm>` within their template. And because both views must have different buttons and actions, I did place the Buttons with in the Create and Edit Components.

The `ContactFormComponent` has the `<form [formGroup]="form">` and `<input formControlName="name">` tags.

Now I can't figure out how to pull the form data out of the `ContactFormComponent` when the Save Button is clicked.

### Thoughts / Ideas:

I could define the `FormGroup` within the Create and Edit Components and then pass the `FormGroup` instance to the Form Component via `@Input`. This way I could read / update / reset the Form Data. But then I had to write the whole `FormGroup` definition and validators twice, though in my opinion this should stay within the Form Component.

(I don't want to use two-way binding on the `@Input` property, because `Contact` is immutable)

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I make the component itself to save (and sometimes retrieve) data. So you check if your input value is provided and then optionally populate form with values, change text on save button from 'add' to 'save' and do backend calls accordingly.

Comment: Then my dumb form must know the `ContactService` and provide functions for Reload, Update, Create, Delete. And have lot's of if/else stuff inside. This way I could delete my Create and Edit Components, because they wouldn't contain any useful code. And I wouldn't be able to reuse the Contact Form somewhere else. Doesn't look like a clean software design to me. :(

Comment: Ive went down this path as well, trying to find a way to consolidate 'create' and 'edit' components.  I ended up relenting and keeping things separated - ie; two components.  For me at least, it keeps things a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I can't figure out how to pull the form data out of the
>   ContactFormComponent when the Save Button is clicked.

Create a `@ViewChild("form") form: ContactForm;`
Then you can call `form.contact` to get the editing contact.

In this case I wouldn't write 2 different component. Just check if current form is creating or editing. So I would stay in the same form, after pushing `Save` button an `Create Form` will become `Edit Form` anyway.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll have a look at it later. Btw: `Create Form` will not always become `Edit Form`. It depends amongst others on who (and why) opened the `Create Form`. E.g. if you're in some other form, where you'd like to reference a Contact, but that Contact doesn't exist yet, then it may be possible to open the `Create Form` in a modal, which is getting closed after successful Save and automatically set the newly created Contact to the reference property. Also the user may choose to instantly create another Contact after creating the first, or go back to Contact List. There are many options.

Comment: @Daniel hi , can you explain a little more..I am facing the same issue and do not how to handle it...I have 2 button in a component where one supposed to display the form (modal) without any values and the other supposed to populate the inputs for editing... not sure what way to go! How to know which button was clicked ? I also want to have only one form component. I am not clear about the `@ViewChild` and how its used in this context!

Comment: @DavidBracoly your case is simpler, just have two different ngClick handler for the two buttons - 
or `ngClick="onClick($event.target)"` where event target is the instance of the clicked button.